# How to convert string to variable for use in server code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want convert $RowNumber from string to a variable, for use in while, do is that possible?!how to do it?

```
$row1 = mysqli_query($Database,"SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY ID");
$row2 = mysqli_query($Database,"SELECT * FROM Table2 ORDER BY ID");
// Others Rows code

for ($num = 1; $num <= 6; $num++)
{
  $RowNumber = "row" . $num;   // Save RowNumber for use in while

  echo '<tr>';
  // when it's used it not work becuse it's just a string only and 
  // i want convert it to variable to use in while
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($RowNumber)) 
  {
    echo  '<td>
        <div class="Image_DIV" id="'; echo $row['DIV_ID'];  echo  '">
          <table>
            <tr><td class="Image"><img class="ImageOfDiv" 
              src="3DGallery/Chosen/Small/'; echo $row['src']; echo '"/></td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="ImageDescribe">'; echo $row['describe']; echo '</td></tr></table>
        </div>
        </td>';
   }
   echo '</tr><tr>';
}
```

Comment: That's not how you use `mysqli_fetch_array()` you need to feed it the returned object from `mysqli_query()`

Comment: Many Thanks Nouphal.M, It's true. i wnat reduce my codes with this command

Comment: Better solution would be to create array with all rows:

$rows[] = mysqli_query....

foreach($rows as $row) {

Comment: Thanks raina77ow and Mahakala Array's good way for create loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Table1` and `Table2` have the same columns then you should `UNION` them together in your SQL then work on a single results set.

```
$results = mysqli_query($Database, "SELECT ID, DIV_ID, src, describe FROM `Table1` UNION SELECT ID, DIV_ID, src, describe FROM `Table2` ORDER BY ID");

echo '<tr>';
$x = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row['DIV_ID'];
    echo $row['src'];
    echo $row['describe'];
    echo '</td>';
    if( ++$x % 3 == 0 ) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Ok, I can use it, but i need add a <tr> tag after every 3 rows, and to do it, i think i can just creat a for or foreach while, thanks

Comment: @user3110164 Edited answer to split output to a new table row after every 3 results as requested.

Comment: Oh my god, it's true, but just need ($x += 1) and (x % 3 == 0) and i think you forgot it, many thanks mr. AeroX

Comment: @user3110164 Yes I realised I made a mistake and have corrected it in the answer. It should have been `if( ++$x % 3 == 0 )`

Answer (score 1):

Try `${$RowNumber}` instead of $RowNumber for your purpose,  If you need more info you can find it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). But as Mr. raina77ow has commented arrays are a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$rows[] = mysqli_query($Database,"SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY ID");
$rows[] =  mysqli_query($Database,"SELECT * FROM Table2 ORDER BY ID");
// Others Rows code

foreach ($rows as $current)
{

  echo '<tr>';
  // loop the query
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($current)) 
  {
    echo  '<td>
        <div class="Image_DIV" id="'; echo $row['DIV_ID'];  echo  '">
          <table>
            <tr><td class="Image"><img class="ImageOfDiv" 
              src="3DGallery/Chosen/Small/'; echo $row['src']; echo '"/></td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="ImageDescribe">'; echo $row['describe']; echo '</td></tr></table>
        </div>
        </td>';
   }
   echo '</tr><tr>';
}
```

You cant assign variables like that without using php Eval: http://www.php.net/eval, but that is realy bad practise!

or using ${$var} syntax. But arrays is probably easier to work with.